# Find index value of a dataframe by comparing with another series

Tags: python, pandas

I am having problem while extracting index value from a data frame by comparing a dataframe column values with another list.

```
list=[a,b,c,d]

  data frame
by comparing list with column X
   X Y Z 
0  a r t
1  e t y
2  c f h
3  d r t
4  b g q
this should return the index values like

  X
0 a
4 b
2 c
3 d
I tried this method

z=dataframe.loc[(dataframe['X'] == list)]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `isin` as you are comparing to a list of elements:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['X','Y','Z'])
dataframe['X'] = ['a','e','c','d','b']
dataframe['Y'] = ['r','t','f','r','g']
dataframe['Z'] = ['t','y','h','y','k']
mylist = ['a','b','c','d']
```

(always post a way to create your dataframe in your question, it will be faster to answer)

```
dataframe[dataframe['X'].isin(mylist)].X

0    a
2    c
3    d
4    b
Name: X, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `isin`:

Make sure your list is a list of strings, then use `dropna` to get rid of unwanted rows and columns.

```
list = ['a','b','c','d']
df[df.isin(list)].dropna(how='all').dropna(axis=1)
```

Or if you only wanted to compare with column X.

```
df.X[df.X.isin(list)]
```

Output:

```
   X
0  a
2  c
3  d
4  b
```